# How can I run the Events created by Tensorboard

Tags: pytorch

I use tensorboard to create an events,

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write=SummaryWriter("log")
    write.add_scalar("test",1,1)
    write.add_scalar("test",2,2)
    write.close()
```

but How can I run it? When I input `tensorboard --logdir=='logs'`, it told me has no exe named tensorboard found.

Comment: are you using anaconda as package manager?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda as package manager, at start menu, search for anaconda prompt. And run it. Install tensorboard there with the command,

`pip install tensorboard`

Then use `cd` to change the directory to the location of your `.py` file.

And there use the command `tensorboard logdir=runs`

Comment: Thank you ,but I don't use anaconda, can pip do this ？  Or  if  something else can instead of it?

Comment: you can try it on cmd but i am not sure about it, btw how you install packages?

Comment: Thanks,I try it ,but it doesnt work,I did't find the tensorboard.exe in my Project,I just find it in the project "Tensorflow-gpu",I can run it only in that project, Maybe tf have a better support. I usually use pip, I've used the anaconda ,but not familiar about it.

Comment: you can do use the pip commands with anaconda manager.

Comment: I have considered to use conda, but I have many env create by pip,if I use anaconda now, maybe the evn will be confusio?   
It seems that people use pytorch, used to use matplotlib to show the progress ,rather than tensorboard.